# SFDX Custom Metadata commands

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-metadata, sfdx-plugin

When I am executing sfdx command to generate custom metadata from custom settings object, I receive error `No sObject with name My_Existing_Object__c found in the org`. However object/custom setting is present in the org and code directory as well.
I am using below command as per SFDX docs:
`sfdx force:cmdt:generate --devname MyCmdt --sobjectname My_Existing_Object__c`

Update: Even `sfdx force:cmdt:record:insert` doesnt seem to work. It is not able to pick the field given in csv which is present in code base :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Custom metadata objects end with `__mdt` and not `__c` like custom objects and custom metadata. I would check the syntax, because that could be confusing the CLI into searching for an object called `My_Existing_Object__c` and not a custom metadata type.

Comment: @nbrown That's not the problem. I checked the docs :D

Comment: Does your org have a namespace (try `MyNS__My_Existing_Object__c`)? Are you using the correct org (check `force:config:list`)?

Comment: Yes my org has namespace and I have tried with prefixing the namespace as well. But it doesn't work. I am using the correct org, I have verified that many times :)

Comment: @nbrown - I am trying to create custom metadata type from existing custom object in the org. So ```__c``` is as per the requirement here.

Comment: Okay, so I tested this out in my org... Same result. I'm not sure what's going on. I'll see if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to do this in a sfdx project
2. your custom object needs to be pulled *locally* into that project
3. you get a weird locking error
4. but it does generate the mdt

[image: Results with weird error]

Comment: That was a quick test object I threw in, there's no records, but schema was created - *remember* it only created it *locally* so you now need to push it to your org

Comment: Ok, scratch that, it creates it *empty*.  Adding the `--loglevel DEBUG` flag gives me ERROR running force:cmdt:generate:  Failed to generate custom metadata. Reason: arr.map is not a function.

Comment: I assume you have your Test__c object in the same directory as well - ```force-app/main/default/objects/```

Comment: Yes, standard project structure, pulling metadata from the org.  the "arr.map is not a function" does look like a JS/Node bug, i.e., the CLI not your use of it or your project

Comment: Tried in both Win cmdline and WSL, same issue - also worth noting that it creates things in force-app/main/default/customMetadata (note the capital M) by default unless you specify a path and you need to run the command from the root of your project.  JS error message notwithstanding